# nodejs use mongoDB username and password Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var DB_CONN_STR = 'mongodb://Jermine:123456@localhost:27017/berk';
var insertData = function(db, callback) {  
    // connect to table site
    var collection = db.collection('user');

}

MongoClient.connect(DB_CONN_STR, function(err, db) {
    console.log("connection successful!");
    insertData(db, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

if I collection localhost:27017, don't use username and password is run ok,but I can`t collection my table with use username and password

Comment: Question is not complete

Comment: Presumably your user and password supplied for the connection is actually incorrect or does not have sufficient privileges. You need to check the `err` result in the callback to `.connect()` and see what the error is. Also though the code does not really use it yet the callback to your function needs an `err` argument as well. Since "two" arguments are returned. i.e `insertData(db, function(err,result) {..` and also check the `err` there inside the defined callback.

Comment: In the callback of `MongoClient.connect`, you need to check `err` and print it -- if `db` is `null`, then there must be some error happened. The "connection successful!" message can only be printed when there is no `err`.